# On-screen keyboard way of sending keys to webpage

Tags: vb.net

I want to create an on-screen Keyboard using VB.net that will send keys to another program (webpage input) that has focus.

I tried this

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TopMost = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Const WS_EX_NOACTIVATE As Int32 = &H8000000
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    SendKeys.Send("A")
End Sub
```

But when I call `SendKeys` to send to webpage input I don't get any result, and when I call `SendKeys` to send to another program like Notepad or Start Menu I get a result. Need help here.

Comment: Start -> Run -> osk.exe. You didn't have to write a single line of code.

Comment: wanna be creative :D
learning using some codes